# Filter out elements in list of lists

Tags: haskell

I want to filter out the number 2 in this list of lists:

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[2,1,3,4]]
```

...so that when I use this length function:

```
noTwos xs = map length [x|x<-xs]
```

I will get the result `[2,1,3]`.

I tried with `[x|x<-xs, x/=[2] ]` but that only filter out the list from `[2]` as elements,  how do I filter out the 2's in all the sublists?

Comment: Have you tried nesting those list comprehensions? The outer one should look like the one in `noTwos`. Instead of collecting the `x`s, do a second list comprehension to filter out the `2`s.

Comment: hm .. i fail to see where I should put the second list comprehension into

Comment: Something like `[ [x | x<-xs, x/=2] | xs<-xss]`

Comment: How does `noTwos xs = map length [x|x<-xs]` really work..?

Comment: Basically `filter (/=2) <$> [[1,2,3],[1,2],[2,1,3,4]]` should suffice.

Comment: `[x | x <- xs]` is redundant. Write `xs` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work fine :

```
map (filter (/= 2)) [[1,2,3],[1,2],[2,1,3,4]]
```

You map over the outer list, and filter each sublist.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Ulrar's `map . filter` version, which is indeed more readable.
Using [List's difference (\\)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:-92--92-) should works too (*importing* `Data.List` *is needed*):

```
no2s = map (\\ [2])
```

*Note*, that this leaves empty lists in case of `[...,[2],...]`

In case you want to get rid of empty lists, just filter them out:

```
no2s = filter (not . null) . map (\\ [2])
```